# MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans after dropna()

Tags: nan

score_matrix, pvalue_matrix, pairs = find_cointegrated_pairs(data) error occurs here. I dropna() but still NaN values stay. I don't understand why. Most NaN values dropped but still some remained. data.isnull().cumsum() returns Ticker  AAPL    AMC AMD AMZN    AUDJPY=X    BABA    BCH-USD BTC-USD BZ=F    CADJPY=X    ... USDJPY=X    VIX XLM-USD XRP-USD ^DJI    ^FCHI   ^FTSE   ^GSPC   ^IXIC   ^RUT
Date
2022-02-01  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2022-02-02  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2022-02-03  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2022-02-04  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2022-02-05  1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   ... 1   5   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2024-03-01  237 237 237 237 216 237 0   0   235 216 ... 216 760 0   0   237 225 235 237 237 237
2024-03-02  238 238 238 238 217 238 0   0   236 217 ... 217 761 0   0   238 226 236 238 238 238
2024-03-03  239 239 239 239 218 239 0   0   237 218 ... 218 762 0   0   239 227 237 239 239 239
2024-03-04  239 239 239 239 218 239 0   0   237 218 ... 218 763 0   0   239 227 237 239 239 239
2024-03-05  239 239 239 239 218 239 0   0   237 218 ... 218 764 0   0   239 227 237 239 239 239

Comment: Hi @wynton lam, Welcome to stack overflow.  This question cannot be answered: your layout is messed up making it hard to understand your question. Seconly, you may want to provide more background information on where your question comes from. E.g. add the programming language?